# Using flatMap on a shared publisher leads to data loss

Tags: swift, combine

For some reason when using a shared publisher flatMap behaves strangely. Instead of receiving all the values I am only getting one. I am mimicking my app's logic in the following example, where a flat mapped publisher sends values on a different queue.

Any ideas why the share logic could have this effect?

```
# swift playground 

import Combine
import XCTest


let shared = (0..<10).publisher
    .share()

let sub = shared
    .flatMap(maxPublishers: .max(1)) { Just($0).subscribe(on: DispatchQueue.global()) }
    .sink { value in
        print("\(value)")
    }

print("waiting...")
_ = XCTWaiter.wait(for: [XCTestExpectation(description: "test")], timeout: 2)
print("done")
```

Here is the output for the playground code

```
0
waiting...
done
```

However if I comment out .share() then everything works as expected, meaning I receive all the 10 values. The output is

```
0
1
2
3
4
waiting...
5
6
7
8
9
done
```

Answer (score 1):

`.share` sends `unlimited` demand upstream, even though it receives a demand of 1 from downstream. You can see it if you put `.print()` operator before and after:

```
let shared = (0..<10).publisher
                     .print("1")
                     .share()
                     .print("2")
```

Because the demand is unlimited, `Sequence` publisher sends all its values synchronously, but because `.flatMap(maxPublishers: .max(1))` only receives one-at-a-time, all the remaining values are simply dropped.

If you don't want to drop them, you could use a `buffer` operator:

```
shared
   .buffer(size: .max, prefetch: .keepFull, whenFull: .dropNewest)
   .flatMap(maxPublishers: .max(1)) { ... }
```

Comment: I guess I don't think this is a bug (nor did you say it was one), since if we propose to share the stream, we cannot coherently respond to backpressure from just _one_ of our possibly multiple subscribers.

Comment: @matt, yeah, that's a good point. One could possibly imagine more complicated schemes of tracking demand, but not without various bizarre outcomes. This choice seems to be by-design.

Comment: @NewDev, if I use .buffer then sharing does not work
I mean that If I create another subscriber it does not get any values.

Comment: @JkMu, sharing doesn't work, because all the values are emitted synchronously at the first request and the `Sequence` publisher completes before the second subscriber even has a chance to connect. You're after something here, but it's not clear what. In any case, this should a different question, and specify there what you want the behavior to be

Comment: @NewDev ah, ok, i switched publisher to emit asynchronously and now both subscribers are getting all the values. Thank you for helping with this.

Comment: @JkMu, just keep in mind that this is potentially brittle. If you want to ensure that a shared publisher is not subscribed to until you're ready (i.e. all subscribers have subscribed) look into using `makeConnectable` or `multicast`